# PostgreSQL querying the current week's data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to grab all the appointments that have been booked for this current week I initially tried this:

```
select * 
from   appointments 
where  staff_id = 'id' 
and   (to_timestamp(appointments.start_time)) > (current_date - interval '1 week') 
and   (to_timestamp(appointments.start_time)) < (current_date + interval '1 week')
```

This just selects all the appointments that equal +/- 7 days, so not the current week. This was my next try. I know its broken but I think it gets the point across.

```
select * 
from   appointments 
where  staff_id = 'id' 
and    (to_timestamp(appointments.start_time)) > (current_date - interval concat(extract(dow from current_date), ' days')) 
and    (to_timestamp(appointments.start_time)) < (current_date + interval concat(7 - extract(dow from current_date), ' days'))
```

How would I go about building this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you agree with Postgres's definition of a week, then you can do:

```
select a.*
from appointments a
where staff_id = 'id' and 
      to_timestamp(appointments.start_time) >= date_trunc('week', current_date) and
      to_timestamp(appointments.start_time) < date_trunc('week', current_date) + interval '1 week';
```